# How to disable wallpaper blur effect on Samsung Galaxy S9 home screen?

Tags: samsung, wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I've set an animated wallpaper on my Samsung Galaxy S9 (one that was included with the device). It displays correctly on the lock screen, but somehow gets blurred on the home screen.

**Lock screen (no blur)** | **Home screen (blur)**

[image] [image]

Is it possible to disable this blur effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not blurred wallpaper, it applied two wallpapers, one for the lock screen and the other for the home screen.

To set the wallpaper (single wallpaper for both screens):

1. Open the wallpaper app, and select any wallpaper, and select this option set as **Home screen and Lock screen** OR set **Both** (option in Google Wallpaper app).
2. Press and hold the home screen, the screen will show three options, Wallpaper, Widgets, and Settings (home screen). Tap on Wallpaper, and select any wallpaper, the select set as HOME screen and Lock screen OR Both as options mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Press the home screen. On the bottom, press launcher themes. Disable the blur effect to all.