# Home screen wallpaper blurs on Samsung Galaxy S20+

Tags: samsung, wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-s-20

On my Samsung Galaxy S20+, the wallpaper is blurred on my home screen but not on the lock screen.

I saw a similar post to this saying to change your lock and home screen wallpaper to different wallpapers, I have tried changing the wallpaper to something not blurry and it still does not work.

How to prevent blur home screen wallpaper?

Comment: There are 2 similar questions related to blurry wallpaper on Samsung: [Use "static" live wallpaper](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163303/44325), [Set home screen wallpaper, or disable blur effect](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207495/44325)